# REGEX help, SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need Regex for a SQL search, something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` REGEXP '$queryWord(\d{1,4})';"
```

except, that i need to include `'='`between the `$queryWord` and `(\d{1,4})` part, not quite sure on how to do this ?

Comment: Fully deserved downvote, this is not constructive, i am well aware of that

Comment: State your question more clearly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: search a SQL database for a word + up to 4 numbers, word is variable, so are the numbers.

The feilds would look like this

potato=123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to get the `\d` to behave, so I used the POSIX `[:digit:]` instead. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE searchWord REGEXP '$queryWord=[[:digit:]]{1,4}'
```

The equals sign doesn't need special handling. In my tests it worked with and without escaping.

You could also do:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE searchWord REGEXP '$queryWord=[0-9]{1,4}'
```

Finally, beware of interpolating string values into your queries. This can leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. See [here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and lots of other places for more information.

Comment: I do escape the string with mysqli_real_escape_string, and if you are wondering this is not my search function, but the first one of 2, rather return an exact match using this, and then search for a %LIKE%

Comment: Excellent, and no worries :) The SQL Injection warning was more or less a reflex - it's pretty much standard practice on StackOverflow nowadays to warn about it when a MySQL query is built by appending or interpolating strings.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape the '='. This should work:

```
"SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` REGEXP '$queryWord\=\d{1,4}'";
```

Note also the lack of a capture group around your numbers. We're checking for them, not returning them.

Comment: +1 @mkumpan for the point about capturing - I'd meant to bring that up myself and forgot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` REGEXP '".$queryWord."\=\d{1,4}';"
```

This would work.

You need to be careful, and make sure your $queryWord has only letter and no special character like dots, etc.